# Multiple Segment is Selected in SegmentController in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

I have add one **SegementController** in **CellForRowAtIndex** method and its selected lasted value which we select previously. But once we move to other screen and come back to current then Segement will select the **multiple option** like this :

[image]

Here "Yes" is already selected and then i select "No",

Here is the code which i write in CellForRowAtIndexPath :

```
   UISegmentedControl *seg = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Yes", @"No", @"Either", nil]];
   seg.frame = CGRectMake(190.0f, 10.0f, 205.0f, 30.0f);
   seg.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
   [seg setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
   seg.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
   [seg addTarget:self action:@selector(segSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
   seg.tag = indexPath.row;
   cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, 150, 30);
   [cell.contentView addSubview:seg];
   seg.selectedSegmentIndex = [[[arryaSegment objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"SelecteKey"] intValue];
```

Comment: I guess you are not reusing the cell properly. Put the complete cellforrowatindex block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not about selecting 2 segments at the same time, but adding two segmentedControls at the same time because you add a new control each time the cell is displayed.

Make sure the code that adds the UISegmentedControl is only called once per cell.

e.g:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell; // = ... dequeue ...
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

        // add segmented control only when creating a new cell
        UISegmentedControl *seg = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Yes", @"No", @"Either", nil]];
        seg.frame = CGRectMake(190.0f, 10.0f, 205.0f, 30.0f);
        seg.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
        [seg setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
        seg.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
        [seg addTarget:self action:@selector(segSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, 150, 30);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:seg];

        seg.tag = 42; // used to reference segmentedControl in dequeued cell. see next line
    }

    UISegmentedControl *seg = (UISegmentedControl *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:42];
    seg.selectedSegmentIndex = [[[arryaSegment objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"SelecteKey"] intValue];

    return cell;
}
```

since you can't use the ugly way of getting the indexPath with the tag of the segmentedControl anymore, you have to use a method which gets the indexPath in a different way. Something like this:

```
- (IBAction)segSelected:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    CGPoint originOfSegmentedControlInTableView = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:originOfSegmentedControlInTableView];
    ...
}
```